# JSONDecodeError at /update_item/ Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I’m a beginner. I have tried everything in the Django E-commerce website course, but it does not work for me. I also tried documentation but I didn’t get any solution. I have this error when I go to /update_item/ and the data is not showing up in the terminal:

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H86lw.png)

tutorial link
[tutorial link](https://youtu.be/woORrr3QNh8)
https://youtu.be/woORrr3QNh8

cart.js

```
 var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var productId = this.dataset.product
    var action = this.dataset.action
    console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
    console.log('USER:', user)
})
}
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

    var url = '/update_item/'

    fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
    })
    .then((response) => {
       return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        location.reload()
    });
}
```

views.py

```
def updateItem(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print("Action",action)
    print("Pordutcs:",productId)  

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer , complete=False)
    orderitem, created = Orderitem.objects.get_or_create(order= order,product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantitiy +1)
    
    
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantity -1)    
    orderitem.save()
    if orderitem.quantity <= 0:
        orderitem.delete()
    return JsonResponse("Item was added", safe=False)
```

store.html

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    {%for i in products %}
    <!-- {{i.image.url}} -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!-- <img class="thumbnail" src="{{i.image.url}}" alt="sorry"> -->
        <img class="thumbnail" src="static{{i.imageURL}}">
        <!-- {% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %} -->
        <div class="box-element product">
            <h6><strong>{{i.name}}</strong></h6>
            <hr>
            <button data-product="{{i.id}}" data-action='add' class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn updatecart">Add
                to Cart</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">View</a>
            <h4 style="display: inline-block; float:right"><strong>Rs {{i.price|floatformat:2}}</strong></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- <img src="static/images/robot.jpg"> -->
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: its a bit confusing to me that you are sending `POST` request, however the error says request method is `GET`

Comment: @aberkb you can ignore/comment these lines, after commenting I am getting the same error  """  customer = request.user.customer
product = Product.objects.POST(id=productId)
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer , complete=False)
orderitem, created = Orderitem.objects.get_or_create(order= order,product=product)
   if action == 'add':
       orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantitiy +1)
       print("adde d d")
   elif action == 'remove':
   orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantity -1)
   orderitem.save()
   if orderitem.quantity <= 0:
   orderitem.delete()"""

Comment: Edit your question with that last comment.  Long strings like that are useless in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a dummy django project with the code you provided to see if I counter such error.
Following JS code I used:

```
function updateUserOrder(){
        console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')
        var url = '/update_item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':5, 'action':'Add'})
        })
        .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
    }
```

I gave dummy data to productId and action.

Then my views.py goes like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print("Action",action)
    print("Pordutcs:",productId)
    return JsonResponse("Item was added", safe=False)
```

Not much with html part, it was just a click button to call the js code.

```
<button onclick="updateUserOrder()">Add</button>
```

And worked like a charm, following is the screenshot of my output in django server:
[image: Output Screenshot]

I would suggest you to try running with the same code.

If error is still there, try giving dummy data to productId and action in js code to make sure if there is a problem with the data in productId and action.

Comment: not working  for me

Comment: are you directly accessing the link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_item/` from the browser? if so that's not you can access that. We can only click the add button and the /update_item/ will be called, we cannot access the link from browser as it is a kind of API.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've solved this issue otherwise,...
if you're using Django version 4.0

change the url for the `cart.js` to `update_item`, `cart.js` should look like this

`cart.js`:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var productId = this.dataset.product
    var action = this.dataset.action
    console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
    console.log('USER:', user)
})
}
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

    var url = 'update_item/'

    fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
    })
    .then((response) => {
       return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        location.reload()
    });
}
```

then import `csrf_exempt` decorator , your views should look like this

views.py(after adding "from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt" to the top of your file)

```
@csrf_exempt
def updateItem(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print("Action",action)
    print("Pordutcs:",productId)  

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer , complete=False)
    orderitem, created = Orderitem.objects.get_or_create(order= order,product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantitiy +1)
    
    
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantity -1)    
    orderitem.save()
    if orderitem.quantity <= 0:
        orderitem.delete()
    return JsonResponse("Item was added", safe=False)
```

Then Clear Your Cache and try adding the item to cart again...it should work this time

Answer (score 0):

var url = '/update_item/'

I checked your code and i realise you didnt add a backslash
Just do that and reload your page then your code will work

Comment: Hi, the question already has that identical line. Please clarify your answer, or delete it if you agree with my comment... Thank you